# Payment from Paypal but no order in Magento 1.6.2

Tags: magento, paypal, payment-gateway

I just found a very strange problem and wondered if anyone has seen the same, or maybe knows a fix for this?

We have paperwork for an order payment received through paypal, but the order doesn't exist when checking the Magento orders admin system?

How is this possible?

Cheers!

Comment: Could it be that the person directly transferred money to your Paypal account?

Comment: Not in this case, as the cart contents were transferred from Magento to Paypal - and are displayed on the Paypal receipt for the order - along with an order number that doesn't exist in Magento... very strange!

Comment: The whole Magento community has this very same issue it is also the case with Auth.net If you do a google search "magento missing orders" you will see a bunch of unanswered threads, I myself have no idea where to start to fix the issue. Your best bet is to ask the customer what happened, log/debug paypal and put a ticket for Magento team to fix. Unless you found something, please enlighten us!

Comment: Not found anything no. It has cropped up two or three times ever, in my systems. That I can handle :-) It shouldn't happen, but for now I can cope.

Comment: This question is most likely belong to http://magento.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Indeed, but it was asked before that existed LOL

Answer (score 2):

I would turn the store off, integrate with paypal sandbox with debugging and place an order to see what paypals response is when the order goes through. You may want to read this thread about a similar issue http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/294965/#t415543

Comment: I'm not able to turn off the store as this is a live store taking orders. I have a development website setup though, so perhaps I can wrangle paypal sandbox into working with that and doing some testing. The problem here is this has only happened once, ever, as far as I know. I don't think this is a bug to be resolved, but more likely a glitch in the system somehow. I'm just puzzled how an order can be created, checked out and paid for, but not appear in the magento system... most peculiar!

Comment: Then enable all logging that you can, in magento, php, mysql etc. So if it happens again you can hopefully debug what it is that happened. On the date the order came in do you have any abandoned carts? Maybe as someone said they sent paypal direct. Unless you have invoice numbers in paypal which magento generated?

Comment: That's exactly the point - the paypal data clearly shows a Magento order number, but Magento doesn't have that order number in the sales admin area. I suspect something glitched at the point that my server was supposed to tell Paypal that all info has been received, and therefore Magento "removed" the order from it's own records - even though a successful payment was received for that order. We happen to know the customer very well, and this missing order came to light when he phoned us to add more items to this "missing" order. I am going to guess it is a glitch rather than a bug?!

Comment: @robgt I would ask the customer if he was returned successfully to the Magento shop after purchasing. Unless it's integrated where the entire transaction is kept on Magento. Ask if he had any strange problems maybe a page didn't complete refreshing etc.